# Combing jQuery Validation with jQuery Notify to show messages

Tags: jquery, validation, notify

I was trying to validate my form with jquery [validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/), and now I want to show errors in jquery [notify](https://notifyjs.com/) plugin. I googled for it did not get the solution. Can you people help me?

What I tried is

```
$('form').validate({
messages: { name:"Enter name",email:"Enter email"},
errorPlacement:{
    $.notify({
        title: "Error:<br>",
        message: this.message
    });
   }
})
```

This code is not working for me. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Whay is notify in errorPlacement? You should use [showErrors](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#showerrors) as in the example in the link.